# How to correctly update parent table based on multiple child table records when not using loops

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to correctly update parent table based on multiple child table records when not using loops?

The solution below uses two temp tables and uses loops to give back correct balance.

`#customer-balance` is the master table while `#CUSTOMER_DEBIT_ENTRIES` is the table with more than one entry.

Is there some other way?

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb.dbo.#CUSTOMER_BALANCE') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #CUSTOMER_BALANCE
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb.dbo.#CUSTOMER_DEBIT_ENTRIES') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #CUSTOMER_DEBIT_ENTRIES  


create table #CUSTOMER_BALANCE 
([RECNUM] decimal(8,0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CUSTOMER_ID][nchar](8) NOT NULL,
[CUST_BALANCE] [decimal] (14,4) DEFAULT((0))
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(RECNUM)
);
INSERT INTO #CUSTOMER_BALANCE 
SELECT 'NGR',1500
UNION
SELECT 'ZGR',100
UNION
SELECT 'MKR',1000
UNION
SELECT 'DKR',1500
GO
SELECT * FROM #CUSTOMER_BALANCE



;create table #CUSTOMER_DEBIT_ENTRIES
([RECNUM] decimal(8,0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CUSTOMER_ID][nchar](8) NOT NULL,
[DEBIT_ENTRY] [decimal] (14,4) DEFAULT((0)),
[PROCESS_FLG] bit default 0,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(RECNUM)
);
INSERT INTO #CUSTOMER_DEBIT_ENTRIES 
SELECT 'NGR',500,0
UNION
SELECT 'ZGR',10,0
UNION
SELECT 'MKR',100,0
UNION
SELECT 'DKR',500,0
UNION
SELECT 'NGR',200,0
UNION
SELECT 'ZGR',20,0
Go

SELECT RECNUM,'#CUSTOMER_BALANCE'  AS TABLE_NAME,CUSTOMER_ID,CUST_BALANCE FROM #CUSTOMER_BALANCE 
SELECT RECNUM,'#CUSTOMER_DEBIT_ENTRIES'  AS TABLE_NAME,CUSTOMER_ID,DEBIT_ENTRY,PROCESS_FLG FROM #CUSTOMER_DEBIT_ENTRIES 

-- WRONG RESULT BELOW
Update #CUSTOMER_BALANCE
SET CUST_BALANCE = c.CUST_BALANCE - d.DEBIT_ENTRY
FROM #CUSTOMER_BALANCE c inner join #CUSTOMER_DEBIT_ENTRIES d
on c.CUSTOMER_ID = d.CUSTOMER_ID


--CORRECT RESULTS BELOW USING WHILE LOOPS

DECLARE @counter INT, @counter1 INT, @RECNUM INT
SET @counter = 0
SET @RECNUM = 0
SET @counter1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #CUSTOMER_DEBIT_ENTRIES WHERE PROCESS_FLG = 0)
WHILE @counter < @counter1
BEGIN
SET @RECNUM = (Select Top 1 RECNUM FROM #CUSTOMER_DEBIT_ENTRIES where PROCESS_FLG = 0)
UPDATE #CUSTOMER_BALANCE
SET CUST_BALANCE = c.CUST_BALANCE - d.DEBIT_ENTRY
FROM #CUSTOMER_BALANCE c inner join (SELECT TOP 1 RECNUM, CUSTOMER_ID,DEBIT_ENTRY,PROCESS_FLG FROM #CUSTOMER_DEBIT_ENTRIES 
WHERE RECNUM = @RECNUM AND PROCESS_FLG = 0) d on c.CUSTOMER_ID = d.CUSTOMER_ID

UPDATE #CUSTOMER_DEBIT_ENTRIES
SET PROCESS_FLG = 1 WHERE RECNUM = @RECNUM
set @counter  = @counter + 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce the number of rows per PK-value to one, in your case using aggregation:

```
Update #CUSTOMER_BALANCE
SET CUST_BALANCE = c.CUST_BALANCE - d.DEBIT_ENTRY
FROM #CUSTOMER_BALANCE c 
inner join
 ( select CUSTOMER_ID, sum(DEBIT_ENTRY) as DEBIT_ENTRY 
   from #CUSTOMER_DEBIT_ENTRIES
   GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
 ) as d
on c.CUSTOMER_ID = d.CUSTOMER_ID
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved using CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS  
( SELECT customer_id, SUM(debit_entry) AS debit_entry  
FROM #CUSTOMER_DEBIT_ENTRIES  
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID  
)  

UPDATE #CUSTOMER_BALANCE  
SET CUST_BALANCE = CB.CUST_BALANCE - cte.DEBIT_ENTRY  
FROM CTE INNER JOIN #CUSTOMER_BALANCE CB   
ON CB.CUSTOMER_ID = CTE.CUSTOMER_ID
```